# Setting up java Logger for a specific package

Tags: java, logging, java.util.logging

could anybody explain to me, how to set up java Logger for various classes from a concrete package ?

for example:
if I get this one and set it up

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client.*");
        logger.setLevel(Level.CONFIG);
        logger.addHandler(new Handler() {

            @Override
            public void close() throws SecurityException {
            }

            @Override
            public void flush() {
            }

            @Override
            public void publish(LogRecord record) {
                // default ConsoleHandler will take care of >= INFO
                if (record.getLevel().intValue() < Level.INFO.intValue()) {
                    System.out.println(record.getMessage());
                }
            }
        });
```

there are conditions like this

`Logger.getLogger(HttpTransport.class.getName()).isLoggable(Level.CONFIG);`

in the library where `HttpTransport` is part of `com.google.api.client.*`

But the problem is, that

```
Logger.getLogger(HttpTransport.class.getName()).isLoggable(Level.CONFIG);
```

is `false` ... like if a different logger was obtained

How else should I set it for all classes from the same package? if there are conditions for loggers for concrete classes like HttpTransport.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You do not want the .* in your package string.
Change

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client.*");
```

to

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.google.api.client");
```

Comment: OMG :-) I spent 30 minutes with this one... Thank you

Comment: It's better to use `Client.class.getName()` than a string as the class name, so if you refactor it won't break your logging.