# Is it possible to enable INFO level log from JSP(Jsp imports Java Classes)?

Tags: java, jsp, java.util.logging

Is it possible to set Log level INFO for all packages from JSP.
In my case,the JSP imports and utilizes various Java classes.
I would like to know if there is a feasibility to do Logger.getLogger in JSP page.

e.g:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.aflt");
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

When I searched for same , I got this link 
[Setting up java Logger for a specific package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291433/setting-up-java-logger-for-a-specific-package/5291490#5291490?newreg=5edfe6df6dac4052902fd82df73e1e04).

But here, logger level is set from Java class.

So, I would like to know if I could do same from JSP page

Comment: formatting and typos

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Because JSP is converted to Java servlet (class). However, you should be careful to retain "strong" references to the logger somewhere.

The following (your) code can lose the log level after GC.

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("com.aflt");
logger.setLevel(Level.INFO);
```

See also javadoc of [`Logger.getLogger()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-).